# Google API Get inbox emails using access_token?

Tags: php, gmail

I am able to get access_token for multiple permissions like emails, contacts, docs, etc. using oAuth 2.0. I have access_token
I got contacts using the following code.

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-  results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$access_token;

$response_contacts=  curl_get_file_contents($url);
```

Now i want to get users Emails using this access_token. 
i used this url . but it gives **`401 unauthorized Error`**

```
$url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom&oauth_token='.$access_token;
$response_emails=  curl_get_file_contents($url);
```

please guide me how can i get emails using access_token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen references to the Gmail feed using `oauth_token` as a request parameter. However, once I used the [OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php) I discovered that you need to pass your OAuth information as an `Authorization` header, as you'll see below.

```
<?php
$now = time();
$consumer = ...; // your own value here
$secret = ...; // your own value here
$nonce = ...; // same value you've been using
$algo = "sha1";
$sigmeth = "HMAC-SHA1";
$av = "1.0";
$scope = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
$path = $scope;
$auth = ...; // an object containing outputs of OAuthGetAccessToken

$args = "oauth_consumer_key=" . urlencode($consumer) .
  "&oauth_nonce=" . urlencode($nonce) .
  "&oauth_signature_method=" . urlencode($sigmeth) .
  "&oauth_timestamp=" . urlencode($now) .
  "&oauth_token=" . urlencode($auth->oauth_token) .
  "&oauth_version=" . urlencode($av);

$base = "GET&" . urlencode($path) . "&" . urlencode($args);

$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac($algo, $base,
  "{$secret}&{$auth->oauth_token_secret}", true));

$url = $path . "?oauth_signature=" . urlencode($sig) . "&" . $args;

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  "http" => array(
    "method" => "GET",
    "header" => "Authorization: OAuth " .
       "oauth_version=\"{$av}\", " .
       "oauth_nonce=\"{$nonce}\", " .
       "oauth_timestamp=\"{$now}\", " .
       "oauth_consumer_key=\"{$consumer}\", " .
       "oauth_token=\"{$auth->oauth_token}\", " .
       "oauth_signature_method=\"{$sigmeth}\", " .
       "oauth_signature=\"{$sig}\"\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$out = file_get_contents($path, false, $context);
?>
```